# What could be the cause of not receiving push notifications through 3g (gsm)?

Tags: push-notifications

When I'm on wifi I get push notifications normally. But if I go on 3g/4g only, I can use the net normally but I am getting no push notifications.

This is the same for several applications that get push notifications, so it's not an application's fault.

I was reading and there seems to be a single appplication in android that passes the push notifications? I was wondering if maybe that application had background traffic blocked by accident or what other reasons there may be.

If not, what other reason may be causing this?

I have mobile data enabled. Other internet stuff works fine.
My android is: 4.4.2

(this is a recent thing, I dunno what may have changed, but imagine a small child messed with my cellphone, it's possible)

Answer (score 2):

I have found this. A while ago I went overseas and got paranoid and turned a bunch of the background data off in the data usage page. Had a play with it tonight and discovered "Google play services" was restricting. Turned it off and tested it, it seems to work. If you haven't already, try that.

Comment: you mean "Google play services" were restricted and that stopped you from getting push notifications? Thanks, I'm trying that... and still no good. I'm basically now going through all the data usage items and enabling them all one by one.